# jQuery keyup function instantly loading results - blocking me from host

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Ok I have a search suggestion dropdown.

When I type something, a character, it will show all results that are %LIKE% the value I entered.

Using the function keyup().

```
    var search = $("#search"),
    result = $('ul.dropdown');
    search.keyup(function(){
        if (search.val() !== "") {
            load();
            $.post('search.php?do=search', {search : search.val()}, function(data){
                if (data == ""){
                    stop_load();
                } else {
                    result.html(data);  
                }
            });
                $.post('search.php?do=search&data', {data : search.val()}, function(msg){
                    stop_load();
                    $('#end_results').html(msg);
                }); /** actual search **/
        } else {
            $('#end_results').html('');
            result.html('');
        }
    });
```

And the PHP for this:

```
    } else { // the info
        $search = htmlentities(trim($_POST['search']));
        $search_query = "'%$search%'";
        $get_search = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `kit_info` WHERE `kit_name` LIKE $search_query LIMIT 10");
        $get_search->execute();
        while ($row = $get_search->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $return .= '<li onClick=\'$("#search").val("'.$row['kit_name'].'");$("ul.dropdown").html("");search();\'>'.$row['kit_name'].'</li>';
        }
        echo $return;
    }
```

As you see, the PHP echoing a list, that will be in the dropdown suggestion.

**Problem**

When user searching for 5 minutes or so, every time typing a new character, etc, my host automatically **blocks that IP for sending too many requests**.

That's because the client has passed his requests limit, and will be blocked for another 24 hours.

A solution I've thought of:

Load all data from mysql, at first when page loads, and then do the actions.

**Question**

Is there any better & easier solution for this besides expanding the limits?

Is my solution great and would work? How would I do this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You could add a timeout that will be refreshed every time the user types something. And only when he doesn't for two seconds you actually grab the suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some quick and easy ways to do this. one of them is to use a timeout.

when i type in 20 characters within 2 seconds, there is no need to do 20 lookups.

Also you might not want to start searching at the first character, but lets say when the user has typed 3 characters.

```
$('#mysearchelement').keyup(function(){

    // stop any old timers to prevent double execution
    if($('#mysearchelement').data("searchtimer") !== undefined) 
    {
        clearTimeout($('#mysearchelement').data("searchtimer"));
    }

    // here we limit to minimum 3 characters before searching, you can omit this.
    if($(this).val().length > 2)
    {
        var timer = setTimeout(mySearchFunction, 500); // wait 500 ms before searching
        // store the timer in the search field so we know if there are any running
        $(this).data("searchtimer", timer);
    }

});    


function mySearchFunction()
{
    //here you do you actual calls to search.
}
```

Comment: the function should work the same as my current one right? with post, etc

Comment: This is only a wrapper to take care of timing. you should put your logic in mySearchFunction().

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Worked excellently for me in the exact same situation!